# DatabaseMetaData multiple tables

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm trying to run a query that joins multiple tables which I then want to use to get column details like the name, etc (whatever I can get) from the resultset.

Using a query with no joins, I would do something like:

```
DatabaseMetaData dmd = connection.getMetaData();
try (ResultSet rs = dmd.getColumns(null, null, tableName, null)) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                String columnName = rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME");
                String columnType = rs.getString("TYPE_NAME");
                Integer columnLength = rs.getInt("COLUMN_SIZE");
                Boolean columnPrimaryKey = false;
                ResultSet primaryKeysSet = columnMeta.getPrimaryKeys(null, null, clazz.getSimpleName());
                while (primaryKeysSet.next()) {
                    if (primaryKeysSet.getString(4).equalsIgnoreCase(columnName)) {
                        columnPrimaryKey = true;
                    }
                }
                Boolean columnNotNull = columnResultSet.getString("NULLABLE").equals("0");
            }
        }
```

However, as far as `dmd.getColumns(null, null, tableName, null)` goes, I'm going to have a problem getting the `tableName` because it's multiple tables.

Is there a way to get column data from a query with joins from multiple tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the same principle, but call  `getMetaData()` on ResultSet of your (join) query.

Here simplified example - you should use preparedStatement

Sorry for using Groovy - but it should be clear how to pass in Java

```
ResultSet rs = dmd.createStatement().executeQuery('select * from ta, tb')  // your join statement here
def rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
def colCount = rsmd.getColumnCount()

println "getColumnCount ${colCount}"

colCount.times {i ->
  println "---------------------------------"
  println "columnName ${rsmd.getColumnName(i+1)}"
  println "columnType ${rsmd.getColumnTypeName(i+1)}"
  println "Precision ${rsmd.getPrecision(i+1)}"
  println "Scale ${rsmd.getScale(i+1)}"
  println "isNullable ${rsmd.isNullable(i+1)}" 
  // Oracle extension
  println "isNCHAR ${rsmd.isNCHAR(i+1)}"  
  // print column value as String
  println rs.getString(i+1)
}
```